# "Syntax error before: '/' " when doing Erlang make

Tags: syntax, erlang, syntax-error

When I do make with my Erlang pjt, some errors come like: memcached.erl:44:10: syntax error before: '/'

Src code:

```
-module(Memcached).
%% External API
-export([set/3, set/5]).
-export([add/3, add/5]).
-export([replace/3, replace/5]).
-export([get/2]).
-export([delete/3, delete/2]).
-export([stats/1]).
%%====================================================================
%% Types
%%====================================================================
%% @type hostport() = {host, string(), port, integer()}. Tuple describing a host and port to connect to
%% @type socket() = {socket, port()}. Tuple describing an existing socket
%% @type memcached_connection() = hostport() | socket().
%% @type memcached_key() = list() | atom().
-type(hostport() :: {host, string(), port, integer()}).
-type(socket() :: {socket, port()}).
-type(memcached_connection() :: hostport() | socket()).
-type(memcached_key() :: list() | atom()).
%%====================================================================
%% External API
%%====================================================================
%% @doc Associate Bytes with Key.
%% @spec set(memcached_connection(), Key::memcached_key(), Bytes::any()) ->
%%         ok | {error, not_stored}
-spec(set/3::(memcached_connection(), memcached_key(), any()) ->
     ok | {error, not_stored}).
set({host, Host, port, Port}, Key, Bytes) ->
set({host, Host, port, Port}, Key, 0, 0, Bytes);
set({socket, Socket}, Key, Bytes) ->
set({socket, Socket}, Key, 0, 0, Bytes).
```

The error is  located at `-spec(set/3::(memcached_connection(), memcached_key(), any())`

I checked many documents trying to solve it but the error is still there. Is there any mis-spelling or misuse of Erlang syntax?

My erl env info:

```
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.1.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V12.1.5  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

Comment: Make sure the module name isn't capitalized. i.e., use `memcached` instead of `Memcached`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is obsolete:

```
-spec(set/3::(memcached_connection(), memcached_key(), any()) ->
     ok | {error, not_stored}).
```

The current syntax is:

```
-spec set(memcached_connection(), memcached_key(), any()) ->
     ok | {error, not_stored}.
```

I tried to figure out which version of Erlang dropped support for the old syntax, but I couldn't find it - must have been a long time ago.